# C++ OpenSSL - SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list order of preference

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

I am using OpenSSL 1.1.0g and set ciphers like

```cpp
char const*cipher_list = "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256";
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx,cipher_list);
```

. I was now naively thinking that the order of preference is as specified inside the `cipher_list` beginning with the highest and ending with the lowest.

But the ssl-server test at https://globalsign.ssllabs.com/analyze.html keeps telling me that the *server has no preference* (see -> https://i.postimg.cc/hvNhfyws/Selection_001.png). Just to be clear, there is no problem with the ciphers, only with their preference order, which seems not to be specified.

I've checked OpenSSL "doc", but I could not find anything explicit about `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list` and preference order.

So how can I specify the order of preference?

Comment: you specify cipher list it on server or client side?

Comment: @C.M. On server side.

Comment: did you see SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE option in openssl docs?

Comment: fyi -- never dealt with this before, just bored right now :)

Comment: Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113009/openssl-server-cipher-selection) too (see answer #2)

Comment: @C.M. I did not consider it, because I think I have no preferences yet. But I'll try and check it.

Comment: looks like OpensSSL server by default honors order of cipher list provided by client (therefore it "doens't have ordering preference" -- it simply removes unsupported ciphers from client's list and takes first one). But you could force server to prefer it's own order with that option

Comment: @C.M Test fails if I include this flag. I dont think this flag is what I want, at least according to doc. What I would like is that server honors order of cipher list provided by client, but if client has no preference then they should agree with servers preference list. So kinda need order of preference for default case if client has no preference. I think thats also the standard way to go.

Comment: What does it mean "client has no preference"? I am not aware of a "no preference" flag sent by client during TLS handshake -- afaik, client sends a suggested list (in order of it's preference) and server decides whether to take client's suggested order into account or not.

Comment: Check comments in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/692529/how-to-set-server-preference-for-tls-cipher-suites) -- might be useful. In particular: _there are two lists - the client's list and the server's list. By convention (because the standard does not specify the behavior), the server honors the client's choice_.

Comment: Great!!! `SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE` is exactly what I was looking for. I recompiled everything and finally got the desired ordered test result similar to other major websites. I guess choosing ciphers based on server's preferences is the way to go nowadays. Thank you very much!!!